# How to run an set of test cases again and again multiple times

Tags: annotations, testng

I have a set of test cases as such:

```
1.@Test
  public void a(){}

2.@Test
  public void b(){}

3.@Test
  public void c(){}

4@Test
  public void d(){}

5.@Test
  public void e(){}
```

What I want is

1. In the first go, it executes all the test cases mentioned.
2. After the first run, I want to execute only the test
   cases numbered 3-5 ten times.

How do I do this?

Comment: have you tried using `"invocationCount"` attribute of `@Test`. Like : `@Test(invocationCount = 10)
  public void c(){}`

Comment: i have tried "invocationCount" what is dose is it try to execute same "public void c(){}" test case again and again, but what i need is first it execute "public void c(){}" then "public void d(){}" and again jump to execute"public void c(){}" in the following manner for 10 times.

Comment: You will have to duplicate (or call the same method) tests that you want to run with different rules

Comment: Thanks  juherr...i was expecting to reduce duplicate code, if there is no other way to do that then i have to follow the same.

Comment: More ideas for the same problems......  thanks